# $_POSt returns unexpected array

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

```
print_r($_POST) returns
```

> 

```
 Array ( [-----------------------------80612539230530
 Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "attach_doc" undefined
 -----------------------------80612539230530 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token" M2gNgjdyAItV3aYLXRgz7DkR5uPDN16esKfeFtKL
 -----------------------------80612539230530 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token" M2gNgjdyAItV3aYLXRgz7DkR5uPDN16esKfeFtKL
 -----------------------------80612539230530 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cl_shipment_id" 30
 -----------------------------80612539230530 )
```

and not the formatted array.

Having the ajax post call as

> 

```
var form_data= new FormData(); 

form_data.append('attach_doc',file); 

form_data.append('_token', $("input[name=_token]").val());

var other_data = $("#store_shipment_frm").serializeArray();

$.each(other_data,function(key,input){

form_data.append(input.name,input.value);

});
 
 $.ajax({       cache: false,       dataType: 'text',       contentType: false,
        processData: false,         url: common_ajax_url+"-----",
        type: "post",       data:form_data,
```

I am using this in Laravel, What wrong:(

Comment: It would help if you explained what isn't working as you expect and what you are expecting. It does look like `file` is undefined though. How are you assigning to that variable in javascript?

Comment: I am not getting $_POST['cl_shipment_id'] value its not defined, How can i get the cl_shipment_id value.

Comment: It seems like cl_shipment_id is 30 for the data you posted. Is that not what you're talking about? I must say, the $_POST array you're showing is pretty confusing to read.

Comment: On $_POST it must have returned me a array like this (
    [_token] => ------
    [data1] => 7
    [data1] => 7588
) so that i can take the values like  $_POST['data1'] but its returning me the content Array ( [-----------------------------80612539230530 Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "data1" 7

Comment: Honestly, I'm a bit confused myself. Could you humor me and try changing the data type to `json`?

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` is a PHP super global, "An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST".

You need to use the HTTP Request that comes with Laravel.

More info at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests

Comment: I have added 
use Illuminate\Http\Request; public function store(Request $request)
and print_r($request->input(''cl_shipment_id')); , Its not working for me on print_r($request->all()); it returns the same array

Comment: What do you expect it to return? Also try use `dump()` in Laravel instead of `print_r()`, it returns a more readable output.

Comment: The post values are coming I am getting the output after fixing a issue, The reason I was confused is that on the console I can see the value on printing $_POST['data1']  but when I open it in a new tab i am getting data1 is undefined ( To see a clear view of the error I use to right click the ajax call in console and open in a new tab ) do any one know why its happening so.

Comment: Hmm, I don't believe you can open an ajax call in a new tab/window. Because if you open a new window, you have to give it an URL and by doing that it will turn into a normal request.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the HTML-Source with the output of that array, you'll see that the array is very well formatted. If you want to see it like that on the HTML-page, you've to wrap it in pre-tags or other tags where you had to apply formatting corresponding to pre-tags.